# How to make a constant that holds a piece of react native code

Tags: reactjs, react-native, constants, coding-style, var

I am new to react native.
After installing the default react natives files.
I wanted to analyze their way of coding.
I noticed that to produce clean code,
they use constants to store particular pieces of codes

Default react native example after installing:

```
 const Section = ({children, title}): Node => {
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';
  return (
    <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
      <Text
        style={[
          styles.sectionTitle,
          {
            color: isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
          },
        ]}>
        {title}
      </Text>
      <Text
        style={[
          styles.sectionDescription,
          {
            color: isDarkMode ? Colors.light : Colors.dark,
          },
        ]}>
        {children}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

I assume that in the above example I copied from the default installed code. Passes the arguments "children" en "title" and then uses it to produce the desired code (kinda like a function call) when referencing/calling "Section". ***My question is how to do the same thing but without passing the variables?***
I tried something like this but it isn't allowed

My code:

```
const header = {
  return (
<View >
  <Image source={require('./Images/img.png')}/>
</View>
);
}
```

Comment: The arguments you're referring to are called props in React. It sounds like you're trying pass a function as a prop? That is supported.
https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: I think so I just want this piece of code to be called from a another place and work. I don't want to pass any "props" as you call them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Kinda like function call" is exactly a function call. It's called arrow functions. Arrow functions are widely used nowadays.

```
const myFirstArrowFunction = () => {
    //your function code
}
```

And just like any function you only add parameters if you need them.

Comment: Do you know what the "Node =>" means?

Comment: Glad I could help. The "=>" is a part of the Arrow function. "Node" refers to what type the function returns in this case an Object of "Node"-type. "Node" is a React-Element (the result of the JSX you write).